# how to persist only the properties that were assigned in spring crudrepository?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm running in to a small problem with persisting an object. Here's an example of what my entity class looks like.

```
@Entity
public class Example(){
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private int number;
    private String sentence;
/* No arg const, getters and setters omitted */
```

CrudRepository Interface:

```
@Repository
public interface ExampleRepository extends CrudRepository<Example, Integer>
{}
```

Service that implements the Interface:

```
@Service
public class ExampleService{
    @Autowired
    public ExampleRepository exampleRepository;
    public void save(Example example){
        exampleRespository.save(example)
    }
}
```

Inside of CommandLineRunner:

```
Example example1 = new Example();
example1.sentence("Hello World!");
exampleService.save(example1);
```

Now the problem that I'm running into is that even though I didn't assign any value to the property number, it is still getting persisted as 0.  How do I stop that property from getting assigned a value of 0 and make it null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
private int number;
```

into

```
private Integer number;
```

Answer (score 0):

the above solution is fine but again if you see in insert query for your save function, It insert all 3 column even you assigned only once column `example1.sentence("Hello World!");`

you can used `@DynamicInsert(true)` `@DynamicUpdate(true)` on Entity level,
this will fire query as

```
insert into example(sentence) values('Hello World!');
```

so query performance will increase